# Fetch the substituted word matched with regex python

Tags: python, regex, substitution, punctuation

Suppose we have a string: "`This is an example.It does not contain space after one sentence.`"
And a matching pattern: "`(\.|,|:|;|!|\)|\])(\s*)([a-zA-Z]*)`"
This pattern matches for any combination where, after punctuation, no space or more than one spaces available. If any of these conditions matches, it substitutes a single space with `\1 \3`. Output of this will be: `This is an example. It does not contain space after one sentence.` (substituted with space)

My question is: As we know that `.It` is our matched string and its index position. **But how we can fetch what exactly substituted at its position? I want to fetch that `. It` (dot space It).**

Note:
Please also consider with the case of multiple matches in a single line.

**Edit:**

Input: `This is text.Another text.Next case`

Output: [". Another",". Next"]

Comment: Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7zk7fe/2).

Comment: @Liju Please check the edit.

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below regex

```
.*?(\.)\s*(\w*)\s
```

**Code**

```py
import re
a="This is text.Another text.Next case"
print([i+" "+j for (i,j) in re.findall(".*?(\.)\s*(\w*)\s",a)])
```

**Output**

```
['. Another', '. Next']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten the alternation listing all the single characters to a character class `[.,:;!)|\]]` to match one of the listed chars.

You can omit the group around `(\s*)` as it will be replaced with a single space, so your will have 2 capturing groups instead of 3.

If there should be at least a single char following, you can use `+` as a quantifier. If you use an asterix, it will match 0+ times. If there is a dot at the end of the string without anything following, you will just add a space at the end of the string.

```
([.,:;!)|\]])\s*([a-zA-Z]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kVZFGC/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/WfPLtN)

To see what the replaced value will be, you can concatenate group 1 and group 2 with a space in between. [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) will return a list of tuples containing the value of group 1 and group 2.

For example

```
import re

regex = r"([.,:;!)|\]])\s*([a-zA-Z]+)"
s = "This is text.Another text.Next case"
print(list(map(lambda x: f"{x[0]} {x[1]}", re.findall(regex, s))))
```

Output

```
['. Another', '. Next']
```